# Why i can't force ASP.NET MVC remote project to rebuild?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know that MVC projects compile on the fly, but lately i have the problem that i need to have a computer with visual studio set along with the availability of the project i need to edit something in (at least it's controllers and config classes!

which is sometimes impossbile specially when i need to make a fast simple edit such as adding a little data annotation for example `[ValidateInput(false)]` which is something doesn't worth the effort to get to my development laptop just to rebuild the whole project in order to feel the effect of the little thing i added, removed, or edited!

so.. any ideas about how to force my online to rebuild? i've tried editing in `web.config` and `Global.asax` but the only thing that work is that i rebuild locally and upload the `.dll` files of the project.

**EDIT:**

I use VS 2013 & the mvc projects are built on MVC5 and .NET 4.5.1

Comment: Only the views are compiled at runtime, the rest of the application is pre-compiled. You will need to edit the controller offline and recompile and redeploy the entire application.

Comment: Could  you try to rephrase your question? I can't make much sense out of this. Could you also provide some more information about your setup? Also, which version of ASP.NET MVC are you talking about?

Comment: Rebuilding and copying up only the .dll files is a really good and quick way to lose version control on your production websites.  Visual Studio has several built in publishing tools that can alleviate many, if not all of these problems.  Also, you should not be pushing code files to the production server.  When VS publishes a site, it only uploads the files it needs to in order for the site to work (css, js, views, the dll files).  The dll files are all of your code files (.cs) compiled.  Even if you could force a rebuild remotely, the source files should not be there!

Comment: @Tommy can you provide me with a walk through those tools? thank you in advance

Comment: @RamyMohamed - sure, let me see what I can find.

Comment: @RamyMohamed - Here is a decent resource that points out how to make a publish profile.  You can publish to the file system, publish via FTP, or use WebDeploy (best option if your host supports it).  Any of these options will compile the site, gather up the files it needs and put those where they need to go.  This way, you are certain that they site you built is the site that has been deployed :)